# Is a CGContext an object?

Tags: objective-c, cgcontext

I've been programming since 2 months (so I'm quite a new) and i'm currently learning how to draw graphics for an iphone app but i need clarification on `CGContext`.
To create the current context we use`CGContextRef currentContext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`, here if I understand well(and please correct me if I'm wrong),`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` create the current context but we assign it to a pointer of type `CGContexRef`.
Is the current context a object allocated memory on the heap or is it just a type of variable on the stack? I know we use pointer to work with the same data and avoid copying big memory blocks (right ?)
but what is really a `CGContext`, an object, a struct or whatever?

Comment: In Xcode, right-click (option-click) on `CGContext` and select Jump to definition. That should give you a good hint. Another hint is that the Core frameworks are C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of these opaque types is that you don't need to know and don't need to care. Apple could change its internals with every release and we wouldn't know (and don't need to). Usually, `FooRef` types are pointers to something. Right now, it's defined as:

```
typedef struct CGContext *CGContextRef;
```

But what `struct CGContext` looks like, we don't know. It *looks* like it's really a CoreFoundation (and maybe Objective-C) object since there are the usual retain/release functions:

```
CGContextRef CGContextRetain (CGContextRef c);
void CGContextRelease (CGContextRef c);
```

The usual CoreFoundation memory naming patterns apply: you don't need to release a `CGContextRef` unless it was returned by a function that contains the words `Create` or `Copy`.

Comment: "Apple could change its internals with every release and we wouldn't know (and don't need to)." this is not true. Core Foundation types are documented to be compatible with NSObject. If Apple changed this, it would break toll-free bridging, amongst other things.

Comment: Adding/removing instance variables/struct members is what I meant, mostly. If we'd see the structs we'd know about that, but we don't and we don't need to. Obviously Apple doesn't want to do changes that break compability. BTW, while you are obviously correct about CF-objects-are-NSObjects when it comes to toll-free bridged objects, I couldn't find anything that guarantees NSObject-compability of non-toll-free bridged CF objects. Can you link to such a document?

Comment: OK, found half an answer: [fish's blog entry about bridging](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/bridge.html) pointed to the definition of `CFRuntimeBase` in [CFRuntime.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.11/CFRuntime.h). Every CF object has an `isa` and thus is an Obj-C object. That doesn't mean it _has_ to be compatible with `NSObject` (class or protocol), though, but of course it would be very strange if it weren't.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: `CGContextRef` is a pointer to a `CGContext`, which is a struct.

A `CGContext` is technically a struct, but it is conceptually an object, but in C, not Objective-C. The Core frameworks are object-oriented C frameworks.

Also, @dandan78's advice is good to help find out what things are.

Answer (score 1):

It's an object disguised as an opaque C pointer. If you cast it to id it will behave like any other object (it wont need explicit retaining/releasing under ARC, can be added to collections, etc). The CGContext API requires it to be cast as a CGContextRef though.

The same goes for all of the Core Foundation `SomethingRef` types. Some, like CFArray can be safely cast to their equivalent Cocoa type (like NSArray). In general, it isn't that useful. It made it easier for people migrate their old Carbon-based code to Cocoa back when people still used Carbon.

Worth remembering that you can do `po` on a CFType in the debugger.